# Drag & Drop using Selenium with Java for automation testing

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I'm working on automation project work using Selenium tool. I am trying to achieve the Drag&Drop concept in Web application, having difficulty to drop the object into the Destination (Drop location). The following piece of code used to achieve this:

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement Destination = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/ul"));
action.moveToElement(element);
action.build().perform();
action.clickAndHold(element).moveToElement(Destination).release(Destination).build();
actions.perform();
```

I'm not supposed to use "move offset"option.

Could you please help me to resolve this issue (or) any suggestions to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [drag-and-drop](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#drag-and-drop)

You could do something like this:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source")); //source
WebElement Destination = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/ul")); //target
actions.dragAndDrop(element, Destination).perform();
```

What is your "*element*" in your code? I can imagine is the "source" element.

Comment: Yes, "element" is source element in my code.The problem is when I started to drag, source "element" changes dynamically.Can you please give solution for how to find dynamic web element.

Comment: Could you edit your question inserting some info about your html?